# MySQL huge IN set for huge table

Tags: mysql

Consider this a theoretical question as much as practical.

One has a table with, say 1.000.000+ records of users and need to pull data for, say 50.000 of them from that table, using user_id only. How would you expect IN to behave? If not good, is it the only option or is there anything else one could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IN functionality has actually pretty poor performance, so this is something I would avoid. Most of the time you can get by by using a joined query, so depending on your database structure you should definitively favor a join over an IN-statement.

Comment: think you're confusing `IN (SELECT ... )` with `IN (value1, value2, ...)`. The first one is indeed notorious for being slow. The second one however, is being rewritten to series of `OR`s, and I don't think you could say `OR`s are slow.

Answer (score 3):

You could insert your search values into a single column temporary table and join on that. I have seen other databases do Bad Things when presented with very large in clauses.

Comment: hmm. i coudn't see how that is possible. `user_id` is unique and is the where condition. He didn't specify about any other conditions too.. then how will you copy and join on that? could you explain a little bit with an example perhaps?

Comment: I meant create a temp table with one column, insert into it the user_id values that he is interested in, then select * from the original table, inner joined with the temp table.  The inner join will limit the results from the regular table to the rows that have matching ID's in the temp table.  The uniqueness is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If IN starts to prove troublesome (as other answerers have suggested it might, you could try rewriting your query using EXISTS instead.

```
SELECT *
    FROM MYTAB
    WHERE MYKEY IN (SELECT KEYVAL
                        FROM MYOTHERTAB
                        WHERE some condition)
```

could become

```
SELECT *
    FROM MYTAB
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM MYOTHERTAB
                      WHERE some condition AND
                            MYTAB.MYKEY = MYOTHERTAB.KEYVAL)
```

I have often found this speeds things up quite a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Use a JOIN to select the data you need.